# Export morethan 150k records in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a requirement where I need to export more than 150k records with powerbi table visual. Is there any  way to do that?

Please help me on this.

Comment: Connect to the data source and read them from there.

Comment: Is there a way to export 150k records from powerbi table?